# geojson file not interpreted properly (wrong format?)

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox, json

My problem:

I am using a web application that uses geojson file to define point data - here is the application:

https://smartcville.com/racks.html

I would like to use the skeleton of the application to make my own maps,
again keeping (different) point data in a geojson file. I typed in the
json file myself, converted it into geojson with a python script, and confirmed with geojsonlint that the data are properly formatted.

Now the PROBLEM:

the geojson file I have put on my own website (just scp-ed it
over). The application does not work any more. I have tried to google for an answer, but, to my surprise, could not find any answers, anywhere.

I figured the following: the original geojson file is here:

```
var bikeGeoJsonUrl = "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5fe9482a4ed34551a883355db0f41164_3.geojson";
```

When I try to load the above geojson file in the browser I get "this is geojson file, what would you like to do, open, save, etc"

My geojson file is on my website:

```
var bikeGeoJsonUrl  = "https://enjoy-virginia.com/geojson/cville-bike-racks.geojson";
```

When I try to load it in the browser, it just loads in as a text file,
so browser thinks it is just a text.

I found that I could actually use myjson.com site to store my text
geojson file and open racks.html file with locations properly.

BUT: I would really want to know how is my geojson file on my website different in format from the way myjson.com is saving the same file?

I also remember a few months ago I had my geojson files stored on github and the applications worked fine, but it has now stopped working.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you have some server application *reading* the geojson?  From what I see you are just posting the geojson file on the webserver but there is no interpretation.  You need something to interpret it on your architecture, like geoserver/openlayers or leaflet or whatever.

Comment: Yes - it is a mapbox/turf application that reads in geojson and then displays the points. It displayed them properly when I save myfile.geojson on myjson.com site, and it does not display them at all when I store exactly the same file on my website ;8-)

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the http response header, you will see that there is a significant difference.

opendata.arcgis.com

- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag
- Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
- Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Bicycle_Rack_Points.geojson
- Content-Encoding: gzip
- Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
- Date: ....
- ETag: ...
- Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 15:25:58 GMT
- Server: ...
- Vary: ...
- Content-Length: 5087
- Connection: keep-alive

your server

- server: nginx
- date: ...
- content-length: 62609
- last-modified: Thu, 24 May 2018 19:43:19 GMT
- etag: ...
- host-header: 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
- x-proxy-cache: MISS
- accept-ranges: bytes
- X-Firefox-Spdy: ...

The response of the opendata.arcgis.com server contains a Content-Type parameter. This parameter is used to identify the right data visualization or program.

See browser application settings.

Comment: Yes - but I cannot wrap my head around that. I use wget (or curl) to get the file from arcgis servet:

Comment: ... continuing: "wget https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5fe9482a4ed34551a883355db0f41164_3.geojson" then I rename the file "mv 5fe9482a4ed34551a883355db0f41164_3.geojson cville-bike-racks.geojson", then I copy the file to my website "scp cville-bike-racks.geojson mywebsite:/geojson". Where does this "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" comes from? I thought that the JSON file is always a plain text file. That is my problem - where it is coded in that "somefile.geojson" is a geojson file, if it is just a plain text file that only follows JSON format?\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629930/force-nginx-to-send-specific-content-type

Comment: mime.types should contain

application/vnd.geo+json geojson;

Comment: OK - but how do I convert my ASCII text file into, say "zipped/UTF-8/Content-Type: application/json" file?

Comment: Essentially, my question is: when I saved myfile.geojson on myjson.com site (see above), what did their software do to my myfile.geojson so the mapbox application can interpret the file correctly? I would like to be able to do it myself on my website.

Comment: I think your file is ok. I can read it without problems.
And i think you have nothing to do with the file on your server.
But i think you have to change the configuration of your server software. So that the sever is able to recognize your file as geojson or json and tell this to the client.

Comment: Aha - so you guys are saying that arcgis server and myjson server recognize that file is geojson using file extension and send that that data alongside in response to the client?  While the server of my hosting provider is not set to recognize geojson file by file extension? So these "variables" like "Content-type", "Content-encoding" are added by the server itself, they are not "written"/"encoded" in the file?